# No distributions at all found, even though I recently published the package

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Hello fellow programmers,

So lately I've been working on a project at my work that we want to open source. It's the package called [`django-push-notifications-manager`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-push-notifications-manager/0.1.1) (yes, what a unusual long name I know).

So I already did the registration and the uploading of the package, but for some kind of reason `pip install django-push-notifications-manager` will not work and will give the error:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-push-notifications-manager
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-push-notifications-manager
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for django-push-notifications-manager
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/pauloostenrijk/.pip/pip.log
```

So I haven't been able to fix it by removing and replacing the package, deleting it, making a new version. None of them worked.

I think you guys would like to know what my `setup.py` was, so hereby:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

import push_notifications


def get_packages(package):
    """
    Return root package and all sub-packages.
    """
    return [dirpath
            for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(package)
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dirpath, '__init__.py'))]

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

version = push_notifications.__version__

if sys.argv[-1] == 'publish':
    os.system('python setup.py sdist upload')
    print("You probably want to also tag the version now:")
    print("  git tag -a %s -m 'version %s'" % (version, version))
    print("  git push --tags")
    sys.exit()

readme = open('README.rst').read()

setup(
    name='django-push-notifications-manager',
    version=version,
    description="""A plug and play package to handle push devices and push notifications for services such as ZeroPush and Urban Airship""",
    long_description=readme,
    author='Paul Oostenrijk',
    author_email='paul@glemma.nl',
    url='https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-push-notifications-manager',
    packages=get_packages('push_notifications'),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'django>=1.5.1',
        'requests>=2.5.1'
    ],
    license="BSD",
    zip_safe=False,
    keywords='django-push-notifications-manager',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
    ],
)
```

Hope any of you guys could help me out! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If I search for your package with `pip search django-push-notifications-manager`, pip correctly finds it. But if I try to install it with `pip install django-push-notifications-manager` I get the same error as you. Maybe its an issue with `sdist upload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending a long time of trying and figuring out I finally found the problem.

Don't look strange to me, but apparently PyPi has problems with the name `django-push-notifications-manager`, I think there can be 2 causes:

- The length of the name
- That having 2 dashes in the name is the maximum

I hope nobody will ever get this problem, it was head cracking!

Thanks for your time!